# how to append data in jquery before finding the key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me how to append data in jquery before finding the key ?
I have for four dropdowns having same attr **(data-dropdown="dropdowns_js")** but different **`key`** (bank, state,district)...I want to append data on `state` dropdown which have `state` key selector.how to find `key ?

here is my code

```
$(function(){
  $('.ifsc_getbankbtn').click(function(){
    var option='<option value="ddd">ss</option>';
    //which have  key`state` append options
    $('[data-dropdown="dropdowns_js"]').attr('key')append(
    option

    )
  })
})
```

https://jsbin.com/rutifesote/edit?html,js,output

keys are dropdown attr see html

Comment: what you mean before finding the key?

Comment: @SarathKumar see dropdown attr in html..i added key

Comment: https://jsbin.com/tojezukadu/1/edit?js,output check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either filter the elements or use this selector:

```
$('[data-dropdown="dropdowns_js"][key="bank"]')
```

You will also need to add `type="button"` to the button or use `event.preventDefault()` so the form does not submit.

```js
$('.ifsc_getbankbtn').click(function(event){

  event.preventDefault()

  var option='<option value="ddd">ss</option>';
  //which have  key`state` append options
  $('[data-dropdown="dropdowns_js"][key="state"]').append(option)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <span>
        <select  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" key="bank">
        <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select Bank</option>
      </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" key="state">
            <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select State</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" key="district">
        <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select District</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" key="branch">
            <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select Branch</option>
        </select>
    </span>

    <button  data-bankdetail="btnbankdetail" class="ifsc_getbankbtn">Get IFSC code</button>
</form>
```